# Context and options menu

Tags: android

What is the problem in this code? My app crashes on click and holding the button

The **activity_main.xml**is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Click and hold on this button" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

the **menu_main.xml**as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Item 1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu2"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Item 2">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu21"
            android:title="Item 2.1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu22"
            android:title="Item 2.2"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu23"
            android:title="Item 2.3"/>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu3"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Item 3"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu4"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Item 4">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:checkableBehavior="single" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/group_item1"
                android:onClick="onGroupItemClick"
                android:title="Red"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/group_item2"
                android:onClick="onGroupItemClick"
                android:title="Green"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/group_item3"
                android:onClick="onGroupItemClick"
                android:title="Blue"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

and the **MainActivity.java**as shown below:
      package com.intents.dedan.contextandoptionmenus;

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.view.ContextMenu;
   import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
   }

   //---Options Menu---
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
   }

    public void onGroupItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.isChecked()) {
        item.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        item.setChecked(true);
    }
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
   }

   //---Context Menu---
   @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
   }
   }
```

The options menu seems to work fine but the context menu is not working.

Comment: Hey, update question with logcat output, so that it becomes helpful to find an answer!

Comment: 11-04 19:51:24.874    1687-    1687/com.intents.dedan.contextandoptionmenus E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler onGroupItemClick in class android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper
            at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:217)